# applescript click every element via gui scripting

Tags: applescript, handler

I'd like to iterate through every element on an iTunes window and try to click on each element.

I'd also like to write to a text file showing each element that I've clicked.

The code that I wrote below isn't working.  Specifically, I get the error **process "iTunes" doesn’t understand the click_an_element message.**

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

```
tell application "iTunes" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"

        set elements to get entire contents of window "iTunes"
        repeat with i from 1 to (length of elements)
            set ele to item i of elements
            click_an_element(ele)
            show_what_you_clicked(ele)
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell


-------handlers------------
to click_an_element(an_element)
    tell application "iTunes" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iTunes"
            try
                click an_element
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end click_an_element

to show_what_you_clicked(thing_to_type)
    tell application "TextEdit" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "TextEdit"
            keystroke thing_to_type
            key code 36
        end tell
    end tell
end show_what_you_clicked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your out of scope  it thinks click_an_element is an itunes function

you need to add "my" to that call

**Edit:** since a had some time over lunch I play around with this a little bit had to turn off clicking because it was clinking minimize button then not giving access to the other items

```
  tell application "iTunes" to activate
  tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        set elements to get entire contents of window "iTunes"
    end tell
    repeat with i from 1 to (length of elements)
        set ele to item i of elements
        --my click_an_element(ele)
        my show_what_you_clicked(description of ele)
    end repeat
  end tell


  -------handlers------------
  to click_an_element(an_element)
    tell application "iTunes" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iTunes"
            try
                click an_element
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
  end click_an_element

  to show_what_you_clicked(thing_to_type)
    tell application "TextEdit" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "TextEdit"
            keystroke thing_to_type
            key code 36
        end tell
    end tell
  end show_what_you_clicked
```